# Statsmodels glm detects perfect separation when it should not

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm attempting to use a poisson regression to analyze the results of an AB test.  The data can be simulated using some of the code below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

def make_ab_test_data(n_samples, pi_c, lift):
    pi_t = pi_c * lift

    y_t = np.random.binomial(n=n_samples, p=pi_t)
    y_c = np.random.binomial(n=n_samples, p=pi_c)

    y = [y_t, y_c]
    X = sm.add_constant([1, 0])
    N = np.ones_like(y) * n_samples

    return y, X, N

y, X, N = make_ab_test_data(10_000, 0.01, 1.1)
```

I'm attempting to analyze the results using `statsmodels` and the `glm` function.  However, when I set up the regression I get an error about perfect separation

```
sm.GLM(y, X, family = sm.families.Poisson(), offset = np.log(N)).fit()


PerfectSeparationError: Perfect separation detected, results not available
```

This shouldn't be happening. Running the same sort of model in R with the same numbers appears to work just fine

```r
# EXample dataset
N <- rep(10000, 2)
y <- c(113, 81)
txt <-c(1, 0)


glm(y~txt + offset(log(N)), family = poisson()) |> 
  summary()

Call:
glm(formula = y ~ txt + offset(log(N)), family = poisson())

Deviance Residuals: 
[1]  0  0

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -4.8159     0.1111 -43.343   <2e-16 ***
txt           0.3329     0.1456   2.287   0.0222 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance:  5.3026e+00  on 1  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: -1.3545e-14  on 0  degrees of freedom
AIC: 16.801

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

How can I run a poisson regression for these data in statsmodels?

Comment: see workaround in https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/3703 using "bfgs" as optimizer. GLM was initially not designed for working with summary data.